# including list_content into list layout to retain ListFragment functionality

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library

First of, I'm using The Android Compatibility Library V4  rev.3 for my 1.6(Donut)

When you first create a ListFragment it displays an indeterminant progress indicator untill you use setListAdabpter(). According to the documentation of ListFragment.onCreateView, if I want to use a custom lay out:

> If you are overriding this method with your own custom content,
>   consider including the standard layout {@link
>   android.R.layout#list_content} in your layout file, so that you
>   continue to retain all of the standard behavior of ListFragment.  In
>   particular, this is currently the only way to have the built-in
>   indeterminant progress state be shown.

The problem is that when I go into my layout file and try:
`<include layout="@android:layout/list_content" ...>` it (eclipse) tells me that

> Resource is not public. (at 'layout' with value '@android:layout/list_content').

I take that to mean `list_content.xml` doesn't exist in my V4 source code. which is correct because according to the docs it appeared in API v11.

I just assumed it would exist in the compatibility library source, don't know if it does...

The only other solution I can see would be to dig android's API V11 source code and copy and paste `list_content.xml`. For now however I would like to avoid this hackery. is this the only solution?

Comment: @Yuyo I ended up not using a custom layout (laziness really), but as me and antonyte said you can just copy the `list_content.xml` into your project. It's not hackery in fact it's the best way to do it if you don't want to start writing lines of code to accomplish the same effect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `ListFragment` included in the compatibility library doesn't appear to use that layout (list_content) as the real one does. This might be because it is offered as a jar and it is not possible to package resources. Here are the contents of its `onCreateView`:

ListFragment from compatibility library:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Context context = getActivity();

    FrameLayout root = new FrameLayout(context);

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------

    LinearLayout pframe = new LinearLayout(context);
    pframe.setId(INTERNAL_PROGRESS_CONTAINER_ID);
    pframe.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    pframe.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    pframe.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    ProgressBar progress = new ProgressBar(context, null,
            android.R.attr.progressBarStyleLarge);
    pframe.addView(progress, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    root.addView(pframe, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------

    FrameLayout lframe = new FrameLayout(context);
    lframe.setId(INTERNAL_LIST_CONTAINER_ID);

    TextView tv = new TextView(getActivity());
    tv.setId(INTERNAL_EMPTY_ID);
    tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    lframe.addView(tv, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

    ListView lv = new ListView(getActivity());
    lv.setId(android.R.id.list);
    lv.setDrawSelectorOnTop(false);
    lframe.addView(lv, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

    root.addView(lframe, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------

    root.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

    return root;
}
```

ListFragment from Android 4.0:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(com.android.internal.R.layout.list_content, container, false);
}
```

Given the choice between copying the layout file from APIv11 source and including this view initialisation code, I think it is clear which one would be considered 'hackery' ;)

Answer (score 2):

I was frustrated to see that the list_content layout was not available using the support library. My approach was simply to reuse the default onCreateView method of the ListFragment and add it as a part of my custom layout:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View listContent = super.onCreateView(inflater, container,
            savedInstanceState);

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_custom_layout, container,
            false);

    FrameLayout listContainer = (FrameLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.my_list_container);

    listContainer.addView(listContent);

    return v;
}
```

I added a FrameLayout where the ListView used to be in my custom layout.

Comment: I upvoted as it seemed like this would be the only way to retain the default "Loading/Indeterminate Progress" view with setListShown(false). Unfortunately it turns out ListFragment from the support library simply doesn't really support that progress view when combined with view for the empty list (@id/android:empty). The implementation [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/ListFragment.java#335) only even tries to find a custom empty view if the default one is not created.

Comment: Can't we just use container instead of calling findViewById. That's where we're telling Android to put the ListView already.

Answer (score 1):

One possible work-around to incorporate default @android.R.layout/list_content into custom layout when using compatibility library is to create a dummy ListFragment:

```
package com.example.app;

import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;

public class ListContentFragment extends ListFragment {
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //Supress default list and empty text behavior
        //super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Then including *this* fragment (instead of recommended list_content layout) into your custom layout:

```
...
<fragment class="com.example.app.ListContentFragment"
    android:layout_weight   ="1" 
    android:layout_width    ="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height   ="0dip" />
...
```

This way you'll get a fully functional default behavior of the ListFragment while still having custom layout for it.