# Two questions about Master/Detail Flow Template

Tags: android

I've just taken a look at the Master/Detail Flow template and I can't figure 2 things out.

1) Why does it require Android version 11 when the code it generates seems to use the Fragment compatibility support? In particular, why can't you generate templates that run off Android version 8? (e.g. this import)

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
```

2) How does the main Activity know whether to show the details in a new Activity or in the details pane if it's big enough? It seems to do it via this code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_list);

    if (findViewById(R.id.item_detail_container) != null) {
        mTwoPane = true;
        ((ItemListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.item_list))
                .setActivateOnItemClick(true);
    }
}
```

`setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_list);` sets the layout to a `ListFragment` which just sets its own adapter but I can't see how `findViewById(R.id.item_detail_container) != null` will ever return true since it never seems to be opened/inflated.

Any clues?

Comment: To be able to call fragment api, your target should be api 11.

Comment: but they aren't Fragments as such. Their import is done via android.support.v4.app.ListFragment; rather than android.app.Fragment So they're compatibility Fragments which should be accessible right back to 1.6

Comment: I guess that is done in order to enable app running on both api4 and api11. With target api 11 you are still able to run the app on api4

Comment: I realise but I want to run the app on an Android 2.2 device. Regardless, my main concern is question 2.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After much looking, the answer is because of this in `values-large/refs.xml`

```
<resources>
    <item type="layout" name="activity_item_list">@layout/activity_item_twopane</item>
</resources>
```

It redirects the request for the normal layout to a larger layout (the two-pane version) where `R.id.item_detail_container` is defined.

This is pretty obfuscated. I'm not sure why they didn't just call the large layout the same as the normal layout but then have different xml.

Comment: Thanks for this, I've been curious about this as well. I've been trying to find documentation which describes the templates and how they work but I have not been able to find any such. Do you know if their exists such documentation?

Comment: I don't know of any. Sorry :)

Comment: I think they use this type of reference because the twopane layout is used in two cases - referenced by values-large and also by values-sw600dp. With your suggested approach (layout-large, layout-sw600dp) you will need to duplicate activity_item_twopane layout, what is not so elegant for future maintenance.

Comment: "activity_item_list" here is an 'alias' that will refer to your normal activity_item layout for phones, or will refer to activity_item_twopane on tablets.  This is because Android OS, when it detects it is running on a tablet, will read your refs.xml in values-sw600dp (for newer tablets) or refs.xml in values-large (for older tablets).  As far as I can tell, it is fine to duplicate refs.xml inside values-sw600dp and values-large.  That's what they do in the book I am reading anyway.

Comment: This helped me with another issue i was having. Thansk!

Answer (score 13):

Here is what worked for me.

1) Add ActionBarSherlock to the project: Project -> Properties -> Android -> Select ActionBarSherlock and press "Add" button. If you don't have ABS, well, you need to get it from http://actionbarsherlock.com/ before proceeding.

2) "AndroidManifest.xml": Set minSdkVersion to 10 (Gingerbread). I think you can go even lower that that.

```
android:minSdkVersion="10"
```

3) "activity_item_list.xml": Just remove "list_content", because Eclipse keeps complaining you need Honeycomb or later.

```
tools:layout="@android:layout/list_content"  <-- remove
```

4) "activity_item_twopane.xml": Remove Honeycomb-or-later lines.

```
android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"  <-- remove
tools:layout="@android:layout/list_content"        <-- remove
```

5) ItemListActivity.java: Use SherlockFragmentActivity.

```
//public class ItemListActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
public class ItemListActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements
```

6) ItemListFragment.java: Modify parameters to setListAdapter().

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // TODO: replace with a real list adapter.
        //setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<DummyContent.DummyItem>(getActivity(),
        //    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
        //    android.R.id.text1, DummyContent.ITEMS));

        int layout = (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) ?
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1 :
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked;

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<DummyContent.DummyItem>(getActivity(),
            layout, DummyContent.ITEMS));
}
```

7) "ItemDetailActivity.java": Use SherlockFragmentActivity and getSupportActionBar().

```
//public class ItemDetailActivity extends FragmentActivity {
public class ItemDetailActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
    ...
    //getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

After making the changes, the app worked in Gingerbread, ICS, and Jelly Bean.

__
sol

Comment: I had set to min api 8 on my manifest.xml, I still could not run it on ver2.2 and 2.3 emulator, what am i missing?

Comment: you saved me at least a couple of hours. i don't understand why android exceptions are that non-descriptive. all i got was the null pointer exception in on finish inflate

Answer (score 2):

with respect at your first question:

you need change in the class `ItemListFragment`:

this:

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<DummyContent.DummyItem>(getActivity(),
                R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
                R.id.text1,
                DummyContent.ITEMS));
```

for this:

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<DummyContent.DummyItem>(getActivity(),
               R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
               R.id.text1,
               DummyContent.ITEMS));
```

And comment in `ItemDetailActivity` this line:

```
// getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Comment: You sir, are awesome!
Though you might as well extend from `ActionBarActivity` and changing to `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`
instead of commenting it out.

Answer (score 0):

i think the Master/Detail Flow template requires api level 11 because it uses the Action Bar. I will try to use this template with [ActionBarSherlcock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) and see if it works whit android 2.2 or 2.3.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the first question, one reason that it requires V11 is that it's using list_content, and that's not included in the compatibility library. A work-around for that is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7863074/including-list-content-into-list-layout-to-retain-listfragment-functionality).

Answer (score 0):

The technique used in the second part of your question is an example of a [Layout Alias](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html#TaskUseAliasFilters).