# Demo Master Detail View - Detail Fragment Change Content

Tags: android, eclipse, android-fragments, adt

Context: I'm using the Wizard with in Eclipse and ADT to get a master detail view framework.

I have a good understanding of the fragments need to sit with in an activity and that with in a view etc how ever looking at the example I'm trying to work out how best to change it so I can start developing a app my self.

Is the 'dummy' content view actually needed ? All it seems to contain is the menu options ?

The questions I have is does any one know how the detail view is created ? From what I am reading the app is just taking the item ID and placing it in the detail view as text ?

Extract from Itemdetailfragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_detail, container, false);
    if (mItem != null) {
        ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.item_detail)).setText(mItem.content);
    }
    return rootView;
}
```

Is the best way to re do a detail fragment for each new screen I need and place some logic behind that or code the existing one to look at the menu option selected and display the right code ?

Finally is this the best example to start working with ?

Comment: Found this which some thing I'm going to try. http://android-er.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/life-cycle-of-masterdetailflow.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The questions I have is does any one know how the detail view is
>   created ? From what I am reading the app is just taking the item ID
>   and placing it in the detail view as text ?

Yes, that is exactly what it is doing. This is done in the detail fragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_team_detail,
            container, false);

    // Show the dummy content as text in a TextView.
    if (mItem != null) {
        ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.team_detail))
                .setText(mItem.content);
    }

    return rootView;
}
```

You need to change it to get whatever data you need from whatever source you want to use (website, database or change the hard coded values

If you look at the DummyContent.java class you will see the comment

> /** TODO: Replace all
>   uses of this class before publishing your app.  */

Basically you should re-write this class to get the data that you want

I've actually added action bar sherlock to make this compatible with api 8 with a little help from this question [Two questions about Master/Detail Flow Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11413943/two-questions-about-master-detail-flow-template)

There is a hint that you could use ContentLoader in conjunction with a ContentProvider to get your data from another source such as a database or a web service